# Underlying class is not converted to json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Question:
Originally command is returning ExecutionResult, which contains Data property of type DomainOperationResult.

Only in one case I need to return some other data, which is defined as CreateOrderCommandResult which is descendant of DomainOperationResult, it contains additional field - Url.

Calling command with swagger, in the debugger, everything is shoing fine, visible id and url with Quick View.

```
Json(result);
```

it shows that it is returning Id and Url properties.

but in swagger, curl, postman, etc. only id is returned, tried everything.
there is no Url in response.

controller is working fine, no middlewares, that may change returned response.

Controller method:

```
{
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] CreateOrderCommand command)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(BadRequest(ModelState));
            }

            var result = await _commandExecutor.ExecuteAsync(command);

            if (result.Success)
            {
                return Json(result);
            }

            return Json(result);
        }
}
```

CreateOrderCommand:

```
{
    public override async Task<CommandExecutionResult> ExecuteAsync()
        {
             // .....
             return await OkAsync(new CreateOrderCommandResult(orderId, payment.RedirectUrl));
        }
}
```

DomainOperationResult:

```
{
    public class DomainOperationResult
    {
        public DomainOperationResult()
        {
        }

        public DomainOperationResult(long id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }

        public long Id { get; }
}
```

CreateOrderCommandResult:

```
{
    public class CreateOrderCommandResult : DomainOperationResult
    {
        public CreateOrderCommandResult()
            : base() { }

        public CreateOrderCommandResult(long id, string url)
            : base(id)
        {
            Url = url;
        }

        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Execution result:

```
public class ExecutionResult
    {
        public ExecutionResult()
        {
        }

        public DomainOperationResult Data { get; set; }

    }
```

returned response:

{
"success": true,
"data": {
"id": 0
},
"error": {
"errors": null
}
}

Comment: Please, is it possible try to set properties without constructor?

Comment: In the Create action method, try to set a break point to check whether the result contains the url or not. Then, you could create a Response Model which has the related properties (id, url, status, etc.), then based on the result to set value for this model, after that return this model.

Comment: Right, I used breakpoint, and it's correctly displaying underlying class, it contains url property. When returning the response, there is no url

Answer (score 0):

Still no idea, why this does not works.

After some digging, found workaround.

`Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json"); return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, new  JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() }));`

returning content like this works ok - at least it generates everything I need.